# Devise confirmation token can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to modify the User sign up through these [Devise direction](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation), but an issue seems to lurk within the form and possibly routes.rb.

To sign up, a user inputs their email.

**The confirmation email:**

```
    <p>Welcome <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

    <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

    <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
   as :user do
        patch '/users/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :patch, :as => :update_user_confirmation
    end
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => "confirmations" }
```

**confirmations/show.html.erb:**

```
    <div class="container">
      <h2> You're almost done! Now create a password to securely access your account.</h2>
        <%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => update_user_confirmation_path, :html => {:method => 'patch'} do |f| %>

          <%= devise_error_messages! %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.text_field :password %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
            <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>
            </div>
            <%= f.hidden_field :confirmation_token %>


            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.submit "Confirm account", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
            </div>
            <% end %>

          </div>
```

**confirmations_controller.rb**

```
    # app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb
    class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
      # Remove the first skip_before_filter (:require_no_authentication) if you
      # don't want to enable logged users to access the confirmation page.
      skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
      skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

      # PUT /resource/confirmation
      def update
        with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
          if @confirmable.has_no_password?
            @confirmable.attempt_set_password(params[:user])
            if @confirmable.valid? and @confirmable.password_match?
              do_confirm
            else
              do_show
              @confirmable.errors.clear #so that we wont render :new
            end
          else
            @confirmable.errors.add(:email, :password_already_set)
          end
        end

        if !@confirmable.errors.empty?
          self.resource = @confirmable
          render 'devise/confirmations/new' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
        end
      end

      # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
      def show
        with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
          if @confirmable.has_no_password?
            do_show
          else
            do_confirm
          end
        end

        unless @confirmable.errors.empty?
          self.resource = @confirmable
          render 'devise/confirmations/new' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path 
        end
      end


      def with_unconfirmed_confirmable
        original_token = params[:confirmation_token]
        confirmation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, original_token)
        @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, original_token)
        if !@confirmable.new_record?
          @confirmable.only_if_unconfirmed {yield}
        end

      end

      def do_show
        original_token = params[:confirmation_token]
        confirmation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, original_token)
        @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, original_token)
        @requires_password = true
        self.resource = @confirmable
        render 'confirmations/show' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
      end

      def do_confirm
        @confirmable.confirm
        set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
        sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, @confirmable)
      end
    end
```

**ConfirmationsController#update**

```
    started PATCH "/users/confirmation" for ::1 at 2016-04-15 16:20:42 -0600
    Processing by ConfirmationsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Vf94s47OKHJKJHU4eutpHnuwCqhZ78Qr/zIOb1qrkr2UnDxlmCtGrR3TNe5hgEIbAWhsntsV0QZZlGp1LozArw==", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirmation_token"=>"JNXxGzLsZjBTQ-9b-cGz"}, "commit"=>"Confirm account"}
      Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.9ms)
      Rendered devise/confirmations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.4ms)
      Rendered searches/_form.html.erb (0.6ms)
      Rendered devise/sessions/_new.html.erb (2.9ms)
      Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
```

**The error (using binding.pry)**

```
    From: app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb @ line 28 ConfirmationsController#update:
     @messages={:confirmation_token=>["can't be blank"], :email=>[], :password=>[], :remember_me=>[]}>
    [2] pry(#<ConfirmationsController>)>
```

The user gets as far as the `http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=JNXxGzLsZjBTQ-9b-cGz` where they can enter a password.  The hidden field confirmation token matches the one sent with the confirmation email but it seems the confirmations controller is not updating the database properly.   Once they select to confirm the form they then receive the error.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solutions lies within the directions from Devise.

Using "For Rails 3/4 & Devise 3.1+", one must use the update and show methods and the protected methods within "For Rails 3/4 & Devise 2.x-3.0" to get this to work.

Solution, combine "For Rails 3/4 & Devise 3.1+" and "For Rails 3/4 & Devise 2.x-3.0" ConfirmaitonsControllers

But why?

```
  # app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb
  class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
    # Remove the first skip_before_filter (:require_no_authentication) if you
    # don't want to enable logged users to access the confirmation page.
    skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

    # PUT /resource/confirmation
    def update
      with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
        if @confirmable.has_no_password?
          @confirmable.attempt_set_password(params[:user])
          if @confirmable.valid? and @confirmable.password_match?
            do_confirm
          else
            do_show
            @confirmable.errors.clear #so that we wont render :new
          end
        else
          @confirmable.errors.add(:email, :password_already_set)
        end
      end

      if !@confirmable.errors.empty?
        self.resource = @confirmable
      render 'confirmations/show' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
      end
    end

    # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
    def show
      with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
        if @confirmable.has_no_password?
          do_show
        else
          do_confirm
        end
      end
      unless @confirmable.errors.empty?
        self.resource = @confirmable
      render 'confirmations/show' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
      end
    end

    protected

   def with_unconfirmed_confirmable
      @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, params[:confirmation_token])
      if !@confirmable.new_record?
        @confirmable.only_if_unconfirmed {yield}
      end
    end

    def do_show
      @confirmation_token = params[:confirmation_token]
      @requires_password = true
      self.resource = @confirmable
      render 'confirmations/show' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
    end

    def do_confirm
      @confirmable.confirm!
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, @confirmable)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter structure is:

```
{
   "user"=>{
       "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
       "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
       "confirmation_token"=>"JNXxGzLsZjBTQ-9b-cGz"
    }
}
```

So when you read the confirmation_token params, you could't use

```
params[:confirmation_token]
```

but

```
params[:user][:confirmation_token]
```

Comment: How and where do you recommend implementing this change?